# AngularJs get route by URL

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Is there a way to get route by URL??

What I mean is I have a route `/users/:id`, I am getting route object using `$route`

`var route_object = ($route.routes['/users/:id']);`

But is it possible to get route with this URL `/users/5`

So when I try

`var route_object = ($route.routes['/users/5']);`

I am getting undefined value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no build-in way to get a route object by corresponding url. However it's pretty easy to do with few lines of code. The idea is to test url against routes regular expressions:

```
var url = '/users/5/';

for (var path in $route.routes) {
    if ($route.routes[path].regexp && $route.routes[path].regexp.test(url)) {
        console.log('found route:', $route.routes[path]); 
    }
}
```

You can wrap it in helper function and put in in some util service maybe or controller:

```
function getRouteByUrl(url) {
    for (var path in $route.routes) {
        if ($route.routes[path].regexp && $route.routes[path].regexp.test(url)) {
            return $route.routes[path]; 
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```